# How do I remove comments in an xml file from Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: r, xml, windows, comments

I have a few large xml files that I want to remove the comments from, so I can use it in a parser (in R).  How do I use Windows Command Prompt to remove the comments or is there something in R that I can use to parse the files with the comments still in it?

Comment: Hmm.. didn't expect `R` to complain for comments in xml. Did it throw error while parsing?

Comment: It did.  There was a stack trace and then an error in data.frame

Comment: Can you give an example of your code. Maybe the comment example.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<original_program>
<source_code name="name" main="false">
//this is the comment
</source_code>

Comment: ^ This is the xml file example

Comment: xmlDataFrame <- xmlToDataFrame(file.choose())
  print(xmlDataFrame)

Comment: ^this is my R code for the xml reader